# Wrong template arguments for Eigen::Spline with Eigen::AutoDiff

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, splines, autodiff

### The Solution from the EDIT is now posted as answer.

### Old Question

I want to include spline interpolation of `Eigen::Spline` into a larger formula and want to determine the derivative of this formula with the help of `Eigen::AutoDiff`.

I tried the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/AutoDiff>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/Splines>

double array[] = {
    1.0, 2.0,
    3.0, 4.0,
    5.0, 1.0,
    6.0, 2.0
};

constexpr size_t nCols=2;
constexpr size_t rowSize=sizeof(array)/sizeof(double)/nCols;
constexpr size_t derOrder=1;

typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,rowSize>,Eigen::Unaligned,Eigen::InnerStride<nCols> > Map;

typedef const Eigen::Spline<double,nCols-1> Spline;

constexpr size_t interpolOrder=3;
constexpr double& xStop=array[nCols*(rowSize-1)];

Spline spline=Eigen::SplineFitting<Spline>::Interpolate(Map(array+1),interpolOrder,Map(static_cast<double*>(array))/xStop);

typedef Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,2> > DerType;

DerType f(const DerType& x){
    DerType ret;
    auto y = spline.derivatives<1>(x.value()/xStop);
//*** Compilation is okay if previous line is substituted with:
// Eigen::Array<double,1,2> y; y << 1.0, 2.0;
    ret.value() = y(0,0);
    ret.derivatives() = x.derivatives()*y(0,0);
    return ret;
}


int main() {
    DerType x(1.0,DerType::DerType(1.0,1.0));

    auto y = f(x);

    std::cout << "\nValue=" << y.value() << "\nDer=" << y.derivatives() << '\n';

    return 0;
}


/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 eigenInterpolAD.cc -o a.exe && (echo \"Running\"; ./a.exe);"
    End:
*/
```

Pityingly, the compilation of the code gives the following error message:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 eigenInterpolAD.cc -o a.exe && (echo "Running"; ./a.exe);
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:254:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:1,
                 from eigenInterpolAD.cc:5:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In instantiation of ‘static void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_check_template_params() [with Derived = Eigen::Array<double, 1, -1, 0, 1, 2>]’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Array.h:195:36:   required from ‘Eigen::Array<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Array(const Eigen::Array<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>&) [with _Scalar = double; int _Rows = 1; int _Cols = -1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 1; int _MaxCols = 2]’
eigenInterpolAD.cc:33:48:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:32:40: error: static assertion failed: INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:657:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT’
       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
       ^
```

How can I avoid the error? Thanks in advance for any helpful hint.

The eigen-version is 3.2.1. Compilation also fails with versions 3.1 and 3.0 of Eigen.

The compiler version is:

`gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)`

Comment: what's the minimum amount of code that causes the error?  Can you remove spline and autodiff to see if error persists?  Also, specify the Eigen version you are using, I am unable to reproduce error with my setup.

Comment: @Anycorn: I have added the eigen version (3.2.1) and the compiler version (g++ 4.8.1). I have also inserted a comment string starting with `//***` that describes minimal changes that make the error disappear. To get `Splines` and `AutoDiff` working together I need the above code. It is already minimized. What is your version of `Eigen` and what compiler do you use? Thank you for considering this question. It is really urgent for me.

Comment: So I really have no idea but it looks like your row size calculation comes out to greater than one whereas the static assert seems to want max row size of one.

Comment: @Anycorn The code runs fine with `hg showconfig; ==>
bundle.mainreporoot=/usr/local/eigen  
paths.default=https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen` and `hg identify ==>
fabd880592ac tip`. Please, post this as an answer and I will accept it. All the official releases do not run.

Comment: @Tobias I really don't have much to post as answer, other than "trying latest repo version blah blah".  You can post your update as an answer tho as it is pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [Anycorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206328/anycorn) pointed out the source code in Section "Old Question" compiles and runs with the very newest version of Eigen on Bitbucket:

```
$hg showconfig
bundle.mainreporoot=/usr/local/eigen
paths.default=https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen
/usr/local/eigen
$hg identify
fabd880592ac tip
/usr/local/eigen
```

I've tested the principle with the following code:

```cpp
/**
     Spline interpolation with AD.
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/AutoDiff>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/Splines>

constexpr const double array[] = {
    1.0, 2.0,
    3.0, 4.0,
    5.0, 1.0,
    6.0, 2.0
};

constexpr size_t nCols=2;
constexpr size_t rowSize=sizeof(array)/sizeof(double)/nCols;
constexpr size_t derOrder=1;

typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,rowSize>,Eigen::Unaligned,Eigen::InnerStride<nCols> > Map;

typedef Eigen::Spline<double,nCols-1> Spline;

constexpr size_t interpolOrder=3;
constexpr double xStart=array[0];
constexpr double xStop=array[nCols*(rowSize-1)];
constexpr double xDelta=xStop-xStart;

const Spline spline=Eigen::SplineFitting<Spline>::Interpolate(Map(
        const_cast<double*>(array)+1),
    interpolOrder,
    (Map(const_cast<double*>(array)).array()-xStart)/xDelta);

typedef Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,2> > DerType;

DerType f(const DerType& x){
    DerType ret;
    auto y = spline.derivatives<1>((x.value()-xStart)/xDelta);
    ret.value() = y(0,0);
    ret.derivatives() = x.derivatives()*y(0,1)/xDelta;
    return ret;
}


int main() {
    std::ofstream of("/temp/test.dat");

    constexpr size_t n=101;
    const double xStart=0.0;
    const double xStop=6.0;
    const double dx=(xStop-xStart)/(n-1);

    double x=xStart;

    for(size_t i=0; i!=n; i++, x+=dx) {
        DerType xAD(x,DerType::DerType(1.0,1.0));
        auto yAD = f(xAD);

        of << x << ' ' << yAD.value() << ' ' << yAD.derivatives()[0] << '\n';
    }

    of.close();

    return 0;
}


/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 eigenInterpolAD.cc -o a.exe && (echo \"Running\"; ./a.exe);"
    End:
*/
```

The following plot of the generated data shows that the code works fine now with the hg-version of Eigen. The red curve is the interpolating spline and the green curve is its derivative.

[image]